# Is there any way to track changes from views in MS Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, change-tracking

I'm looking for how to track changes from a view in MS Sql-Server 2012. And,  the role of the log-in user is Public. So, it's hard to do it.

For example, Assuming that there is the schema.

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[USER_CREDENTIAL](
    [USERID] [nvarchar](48) NOT NULL,
    [VALID_FROM] DATETIME NULL,
    [EXPIRED_AT] DATETIME NULL, 
    [CREDENTIAL_ID] int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [UNIQUE_USERID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED( [USERID] ASC)
) ; 


CREATE VIEW [VIEW_OF_USER_CREDENTIAL] as 
SELECT * FROM dbo.[USER_CREDENTIAL];
```

It can be only permitted to access the view. The view will be changed when some data is inserted/updated/deleted from the USER_CREDENTIAL table. I will do query to the view.

I saw [the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/track-data-changes-sql-server). I tried that, but the target to track should be the data table and the login user is lack of the role. I got the error message.

```
Object 'foo' is of a data type that is not supported by the CHANGETABLE function. The object must be a user-defined table.
```

I tried the following. I added the temporary table and the trigger which make changed-data be inserted to the temporary table when the view is changed.  But, it was also failed because it was permission denied.

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.[CHANGES_FROM_A_VIEW] (
    [VERSION] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
    [USERID] [nvarchar](48) NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [UNIQUE_VERSION] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [VERSION] ASC) 
)

CREATE TRIGGER [SOMETHING_CHANGED] ON dbo.[VIEW_OF_USER_CREDENTIAL] ... 

ALTER DATABASE database_name
SET CHANGE_TRACKING = ON (CHANGE_RETENTION = 2 DAYS,AUTO_CLEANUP = ON)

ALTER TABLE [CHANGES_FROM_A_VIEW]
ENABLE CHANGE_TRACKING WITH (TRACK_COLUMNS_UPDATED = ON)

SELECT * FROM CHANGETABLE(CHANGES dbo.CHANGES_FROM_A_VIEW, 0) AS C
```

Anyone knows any way to solve this?

Comment: You're asking how to audit user actions, not how to track changes to tables.

Comment: You can't define `AFTER` triggers on views. You can define `INSTEAD OF` triggers, but it's not clear those will do what you want either. In general, the engine cannot know or track if the "contents" of a view "changed" based on the underlying table. What's your actual scenario -- what is the data you're trying to track and where does it live?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I really want to track changes of a table. but, it's not permitted. So, I'm trying to track changes of the view related to the table. It's only able to access the view.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I appended an example and smae explanation. Is it going to be clear?

Comment: @AhnDennis there's no such thing as changes to a view. The view doesn't have any data. Again, what you ask is *auditing*. Change tracking is the mechanism you thought could implement this, but it really isn't a good fit - do you really not care for changes made 3 days in the past or earlier? Using INSTEAD OF triggers is probably a better option. Or auditing at the *application* level

Comment: @AhnDennis you should probably look at temporal tables too. They may not be available in SQL Server 2012 but you can implement them with triggers that copy the original versions of modified/deleted rows to a History table

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks. I don't care about auditing. the as-is process to track changes is to poll the view periodically on application level. If some changes are found, my application begins to retrieve the data and process the one. On doing it, it's mandatory to distinguish new changes from the processed things.  So, I'm looking for another way to improve the as-is process on DB level.